# IIS always change a 403 to 404 Error

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, iis, url-rewriting

I am having a strange problem, i have written a code for 403 Error in Application_Error Event in Global.asax file. What this code does it replaces .asp extension with .aspx here is the code

```
HttpException serverError = Server.GetLastError() as HttpException;
if (null != serverError)
{
    int errorCode = serverError.GetHttpCode();
    if (404 == errorCode)
    {
        Server.ClearError();
        Server.Transfer("Error.aspx");
    }
    if (403 == errorCode)
    {
        Response.Redirect(Request.Url.ToString().Replace(".asp", ".aspx"));
    }
}
```

it works fine on localhost but on IIS when i type Default.asp Page it gives me 404 error. and another issue is that i have created an Error Page. but it only shows Error page for .aspx pages. any ideas, please?

URL rewrite module which i tried is

```
<rewrite>
      <rules>
        <rule name="aspToASPNET">
          <match url="^(.*).asp$" />
          <action type="Rewrite" url="{R:1}.aspx" />
        </rule>
      </rules>
    </rewrite>
```

Comment: Did you try set `<modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true" />`?

Comment: yes,, as i said it is working fine on localhost but when it goes live.. problem is there.

Comment: Did you try use URL Rewrite Module for IIS instead of code?

Comment: yes i tried url rewriting first. but that didnt work aswell. so after that i tried doing it with the code, which worked on localhost.

Comment: Post your rewrite config please

Comment: try setting your app poop pipeline mode to "classic"

Comment: Still nothing.. changes the pipeline mode to classic aswell